# Autoclose the approve PayPal window in the PayPal Orders REST API v2?

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

After you

0. generate a bearer token and
1. create an order with the PayPal REST API,

```sh
# step 0: get token
curl  --request POST --compressed --silent  'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token'  --header 'accept: application/json'  --header 'accept-language: en_us'  --user '<clientid>:<secret>'  --data 'grant_type=client_credentials'

# step 1: create the order (use the token from step 0)
curl  --request POST --compressed --silent  'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders'  --header 'content-type: application/json'  --header 'authorization: bearer <token>' \
  --data '{
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units": [{"amount":              {"value":"10.00", "currency_code":"USD"},
                        "description":         "hello",
                        "application_context": {"brand_name":"mybrand", "shipping_preference":"NO_SHIPPING", "return_url":""}}]
  }'
```

you show the user the approval page, where he can enter his credentials and approve the payment:

```sh
# step 2: show the user the approval page
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?<order_id>
```

I'm trying to implement step 2 in  the client, with Javascript, **without** redirects (ie. without passing a `return_url` to `/checkout/orders` in step 1), and **without** using the [PayPal buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) that come with the JS SDK.

This means you open a new window

```js
window.open('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?<order_id>')
```

and let the user do his thing.

I've got everything working well, except the part that closes the approval window in step 2.

After the user logs in and approves the order in the newly created window, how can I automatically close it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you aren't using that JS SDK's PayPal button? It is engineered to solve precisely this problem for all use cases, seems you're 'reimplementing a wheel'

Comment: In particular your use of `window.open(` is likely to be blocked by more aggressive browsers, which is no good at all

Comment: PayPal is calling something equivalent under the hood, and it's running in the same browser just fine. Is just a JS library, nothing special.

Comment: Like I said, more aggressive browsers will probably not be so friendly to your "equivalent" implementation. Good luck with it, although the question stands about why you aren't using what's already built to do exactly this

Comment: What do you think the PayPal JS SDK is using, then, to launch the popup? Whatever it is they're using, I can use the same thing.

Comment: I don't know the details, you can load the JS SDK with &debug=true if you really want to copy it. But the question remains: why are you doing so?